# Given 3 spheres, find the equation of the plane that touches each of the spheres on the same side..?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, conic-sections

I have a problem I am trying to solve, but I have no idea how to solve it.

If I have 3 spheres, $A(1, 2, 0), B(4, 5, 0), \text{ and } C(1, 3, 2)$ of radius 1, how would I go about finding the equation of the form $ax + by +cz = d$ of the plane which touches each of the spheres on the same side..?

I have been racking my brain all day, but I can't seem to figure it out.

If someone wouldnt mind lending a hand, It would be much appreciated..

Thanks
Corey

Comment: How is "on the same side" defined?

Comment: @joriki I assume he means that the three spheres need to be in the same half-space that is induced by the plane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they all have the same radius, the problem can be easily solved. The plane needs to be parallel to the plane that contains the three centers; This yields the parameters $a, b, c$. Choosing the right distance to the plane that contains the centers gives you the two possible values for $d$.

Comment: Excellent hint!

Comment: Hey, Thanks heaps for that hint, it was very helpful. I think I have the plane that goes through the sphere centers as given by $6x - 6y + 3z = 6$, but how do I find d for the plane that touches the spheres ? Thanks again, Corey

Comment: Your plane is wrong, it doesn't contain the third center $(1, 3, 2)$.

Comment: Hey @dominik, Yes sorry I corrected it. Thanks

Comment: I think you mean $6x - 6y + 3z = -6$, or equivalently $2x - 2y + z = -2$. Now you need to take a look at the formula that calculates the distance between two parallel planes to find the correct solutions for $d$.

Comment: Hey, thanks heaps for that, It was a great help. I got the result that the equations of the planes that touch the spheres from the same side are $6x - 6y + 3z = \pm \frac{12}{9}$. Thanks again, Corey

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to find a formula for the perpendicular distance between a point and a plane. The formula will give negative and positive distances for points on opposite sides of the plane, which will deal with "the same side" part of the question, assuming you know what "the same side" means here. (I don't *know* what it means from your statement of the problem, but I could make a plausible guess).

So in the general case, the distance of the plane from the center of each sphere gives 3 equations. Your equation of the plane apparently has four unknowns, but the plane $kax + kby + kcz = kd$ is the same as the plane $ax + by + cz = d$ for any non-zero value of $k$.